# How to build a library directly from object files with CMake

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, object-files

Given a set of object files, how would you build a static library with CMake ?

With autotools I would do

```
libXXX.a: $(OBJFILES)
    $(AR) cru $@ $(OBJFILES)
    $(RANLIB) $@
```

OBJFILES being a list of object files.

How to do that in CMake ?

EDIT: I can't recompile the original cxx files, I have to use the object files (*.o) to create the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [custom command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_command), something like:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT libXXX.a COMMAND ${AR} cru ${OBJFILES} ).
```

If necessary you can use [add_custom_target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_target) and [add_dependencies](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_dependencies) to add your libXXX.a to a specific target, or perhaps to customize the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Use `add_library` in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(XXX STATIC foo.c bar.cc baz.cxx)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the point here is that I have the object files and I can't recompile the cxx files. Thus I just want to use the existing object files to create a library.